# Failure encoding files in base64 java

Tags: java, file, base64

I have this class to encode and decode a file. When I run the class with .txt files the result is successfully. But when I run the code with .jpg or .doc I can not open the file or it is not equals to original. I don’t know why this is happening. I have modified this class
http://myjeeva.com/convert-image-to-string-and-string-to-image-in-java.html. But i want change this line

```
byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
```

for

```
byte example[] = new byte[1024];
```

and read the file so many times how we need. Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

  public class Encode {
```

Input = Input file root - Output = Output file root - imageDataString =String encoded

```
  String input;
  String output;
  String imageDataString;


  public void setFileInput(String input){
    this.input=input;
  }

  public void setFileOutput(String output){
    this.output=output;
  }

  public String getFileInput(){
    return input;
  }

  public String getFileOutput(){
    return output;
  }

  public String getEncodeString(){
    return  imageDataString;
  }

  public String processCode(){
    StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

    try{
        File fileInput= new File( getFileInput() );
        FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(fileInput);
```

i have seen in examples that people create a byte[] with the same length than the file. I don´t want this because i will not know what  length will have the file.

```
        byte buff[] = new byte[1024];

        int r = 0;

        while ( ( r = imageInFile.read( buff)) > 0 ) {

          String imageData = encodeImage(buff);

          sb.append( imageData);

          if ( imageInFile.available() <= 0 ) {
            break;
          }
        }



       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found" + e);
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while reading the file " + ioe);

    } 

        imageDataString = sb.toString();

       return imageDataString;
}  


  public  void processDecode(String str) throws IOException{

      byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(str);
      File fileOutput= new File( getFileOutput());
      FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream( fileOutput);

      imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);
      imageOutFile.close();

}

 public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray) {

      return  Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString( imageByteArray);

    }

    public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) {
      return  Base64.getDecoder().decode(  imageDataString);  

    }


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Encode a = new Encode();

    a.setFileInput( "C://Users//xxx//Desktop//original.doc");
    a.setFileOutput("C://Users//xxx//Desktop//original-copied.doc");

    a.processCode( );

    a.processDecode( a.getEncodeString());

    System.out.println("C O P I E D");
  }
}
```

I tried changing

```
String imageData = encodeImage(buff);
```

for

```
String imageData = encodeImage(buff,r);
```

and the method encodeImage

```
public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray, int r) {

     byte[] aux = new byte[r];

     for ( int i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
       aux[i] = imageByteArray[i];

       if ( aux[i] <= 0 ) {
         break;
       }
     }
return  Base64.getDecoder().decode(  aux);
}
```

But i have the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits
```

Comment: Thank you. Your question lead me to a better conclusion. I missed to send a base64 image, whille I believed to do so. Therefore I received an IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two problems in your program.

The first, as mentioned in by @Joop Eggen, is that you are not handling your input correctly.

In fact, Java does not promise you that even in the middle of the file, you'll be reading the entire 1024 bytes. It could just read 50 bytes, and tell you it read 50 bytes, and then the next time it will read 50 bytes more.

Suppose you read 1024 bytes in the previous round. And now, in the current round, you're only reading 50. Your byte array now contains 50 of the new bytes, and the rest are the old bytes from the previous read!

So you always need to copy the exact number of bytes copied to a new array, and pass that on to your encoding function.

So, to fix this particular problem, you'll need to do something like:

```
 while ( ( r = imageInFile.read( buff)) > 0 ) {

      byte[] realBuff = Arrays.copyOf( buff, r );

      String imageData = encodeImage(realBuff);

      ...
 }
```

---

However, this is not the only problem here. Your real problem is with the Base64 encoding itself.

What Base64 does is take your bytes, break them into 6-bit chunks, and then treat each of those chunks as a number between N 0 and 63. Then it takes the Nth character from its character table, to represent that chunk.

But this means it can't just encode a single byte or two bytes, because a byte contains 8 bits, and which means one chunk of 6 bits, and 2 leftover bits. Two bytes have 16 bits. Thats 2 chunks of 6 bits, and 4 leftover bits.

To solve this problem, Base64 always encodes 3 consecutive bytes. If the input does not divide evenly by three, it **adds additional zero bits**.

Here is a little program that demonstrates the problem:

```
package testing;

import java.util.Base64;

public class SimpleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // An array containing six bytes to encode and decode.
        byte[] fullArray = { 0b01010101, (byte) 0b11110000, (byte)0b10101010, 0b00001111, (byte)0b11001100, 0b00110011 };

        // The same array broken into three chunks of two bytes.

        byte[][] threeTwoByteArrays = {
            {       0b01010101, (byte) 0b11110000 },
            { (byte)0b10101010,        0b00001111 },
            { (byte)0b11001100,        0b00110011 }
        };
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding();

        // Encode the full array

        String encodedFullArray = encoder.encodeToString(fullArray);

        // Encode the three chunks consecutively 

        StringBuilder encodedStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for ( byte [] twoByteArray : threeTwoByteArrays ) {
            encodedStringBuilder.append(encoder.encodeToString(twoByteArray));
        }
        String encodedInChunks = encodedStringBuilder.toString();

        System.out.println("Encoded full array: " + encodedFullArray);
        System.out.println("Encoded in chunks of two bytes: " + encodedInChunks);

        // Now  decode the two resulting strings

        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();

        byte[] decodedFromFull = decoder.decode(encodedFullArray);   
        System.out.println("Byte array decoded from full: " + byteArrayBinaryString(decodedFromFull));

        byte[] decodedFromChunked = decoder.decode(encodedInChunks);
        System.out.println("Byte array decoded from chunks: " + byteArrayBinaryString(decodedFromChunked));
    }

    /**
     * Convert a byte array to a string representation in binary
     */
    public static String byteArrayBinaryString( byte[] bytes ) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('[');
        for ( byte b : bytes ) {
            sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(Byte.toUnsignedInt(b))).append(',');
        }
        if ( sb.length() > 1) {
            sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, ']');
        } else {
            sb.append(']');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

So, imagine my 6-byte array is your image file. And imagine that your buffer is not reading 1024 bytes but 2 bytes each time. This is going to be the output of the encoding:

```
Encoded full array: VfCqD8wz
Encoded in chunks of two bytes: VfAqg8zDM
```

As you can see, the encoding of the full array gave us 8 characters. Each group of three bytes is converted into four chunks of 6 bits, which in turn are converted into four characters.

But the encoding of the three two-byte arrays gave you a string of 9 characters. It's a completely different string! Each group of two bytes was extended to three chunks of 6 bits by padding with zeros. And since you asked for no padding, it produces only 3 characters, without the extra `=` that usually marks when the number of bytes is not divisible by 3.

The output from the part of the program that decodes the 8-character, correct encoded string is fine:

```
Byte array decoded from full: [1010101,11110000,10101010,1111,11001100,110011]
```

But the result from attempting to decode the 9-character, incorrect encoded string is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Last unit does not have enough valid bits
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:734)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
    at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
    at testing.SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:34)
```

Not good! A good base64 string should always have multiples of 4 characters, and we only have 9.

Since you chose a buffer size of 1024, which is not a multiple of 3, that problem *will* happen. You need to encode a multiple of 3 bytes each time to produce the proper string. So in fact, you need to create a buffer sized `3072` or something like that.

But because of the first problem, be very careful at what you pass to the encoder. Because it can always happen that you'll be reading less than `3072` bytes. And then, if the number is not divisible by three, the same problem will occur.

Comment: Thanks for your time to make the answer.  I have understand better the base64. Im going to modify my class with your advices.

Comment: @JGG Take a look at the method `Base64.Encoder.wrap(OutputStream)`. It creates an output stream where you can write the bytes in chunks without having the problem I mentioned (e.g. you can write 1024 bytes every time, and after you close the stream you'll have the proper encoded data in its output).

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

```
    while ( ( r = imageInFile.read( buff)) > 0 ) {
      String imageData = encodeImage(buff);
```

`read` returns -1 on end-of-file *or* the *actual number of bytes* that were read.

So the last `buff` might not be totally read, and even contain garbage from any prior read. So you need to use `r`.

As this is an assignment, the rest is up to you.

By the way:

```
 byte[] array = new byte[1024]
```

is more conventional in Java. The syntax:

```
 byte array[] = ...
```

was for compatibility with C/C++.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i have added aditional information. I tried run the class using r but i had a compilation problem and i didnt find solution